# I am not getting image in push notifications when I triggered it from firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

The below is the code for notification. Can anyone say what is the mistake or is there any code to add to get the image displayed in notification tray. I am using local notifications plugin to get the notifications. The below is the code for notification. Can anyone say what is the mistake or is there any code to add to get the image displayed in notification tray. I am using local notifications plugin to get the notifications.

```
            class LocalNotificationService {
              static var userId = SharedUtils.getString('UserId');
              FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
              static final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _notificationsPlugin =
                  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
              static getText() {
                String title;
                String body;
              }
            
              static void initialize(BuildContext context) {
                final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
                    InitializationSettings(
                        android: AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher"),
                        iOS: IOSInitializationSettings(
                            requestSoundPermission: false,
                            requestBadgePermission: false,
                            requestAlertPermission: false));
            
                _notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
                    onSelectNotification: (String route) async {
                  String userId = SharedUtils.getString('UserId');
                  if (userId.isEmpty && userId == "") {
                    SharedUtils.setString('route', route);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()));
                  } else {
                    Navigator.of(Utils.navigatorKey.currentContext)
                        .push(Routes.generateRoute(route));
                  }
                });
              }
            
              static Future initializeFCM(String userId) async {
                String uId = userId + "userSpecific";
                FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("public");
                FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic(uId);
                print(">>>>>>> fcm started $uId");
                FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) {
                  print("fcm token >>> " + value);
                });
              }
            
              static void display(RemoteMessage message) async {
                AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
                    'high_importance_channel', // id
                    'High Importance Notifications', // title
                    //'This channel is used for important notifications.', // description
                    importance: Importance.high,
                    playSound: true);
            
                try {
                  final id = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
                  final NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
                      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                    channel.id,
                    channel.name,
                    //channel.description,
                    color: Colors.blue,
            
                    playSound: true,
                    icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
                  ));
            
                  await _notificationsPlugin.show(
                    id,
                    message.notification.title,
                    message.notification.body,
                    notificationDetails,
                    payload: message.data["route"],
                  );
                } on Exception catch (e) {
                  debugPrint(e.toString());
                }
              }
            
              static onForeground() {
                Map notificationData;
                FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
                  // LocalNotificationService.initializeFCM(userId);
                  if (message.notification != null) {
                    notificationData = {
                      "title": message.notification.title,
                      "body": message.notification.body
                    };
                  }
                  LocalNotificationService.display(message);
                });
                return notificationData;
              }
            
              static onTerminated() {
                FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {
                  if (message != null) {
                    final routeFromMessage = message.data["route"];
                    debugPrint('Route called for terminated state***************');
                    String userId = SharedUtils.getString('UserId');
                    if (userId.isEmpty && userId == "") {
                      SharedUtils.setString('route', routeFromMessage);
                      Navigator.push(Utils.navigatorKey.currentContext,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()));
                    } else {
                      Navigator.of(Utils.navigatorKey.currentContext)
                          .push(Routes.generateRoute(routeFromMessage));
                    }
                  }
                });
              }
            
              static onMessageOpened() {
                FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
                  final routeFromMessage = message.data["route"];
                  print('Route called for background***************');
                  String userId = SharedUtils.getString('UserId');
                  Map notificationData = {
                    "title": message.notification.title,
                    "body": message.notification.body
                  };
                  if (userId.isEmpty && userId == "") {
                    SharedUtils.setString('route', routeFromMessage);
                    Navigator.push(Utils.navigatorKey.currentContext,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginView()));
                  } else {
                    Navigator.of(Utils.navigatorKey.currentContext, rootNavigator: true)
                        .push(Routes.generateRoute(routeFromMessage));
                  }
                  return notificationData;
                });
              }
            }
```

Comment: you can received image in "message['data']['image']" from firebase notification payload.

Comment: But I am not receiving